# Kivy Garden fails with error

Tags: kivy

I have downloaded the prepackaged Kivy zip file onto a Windows 8.1 machine and installed Kivy-Garden using pip (after running kivy.bat).  However, I have been unable to successfully use Kivy-Garden.  I have attempted the following commands:

```
garden install graph
garden list
```

However, neither of them work.  They both result in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\kivy\Python27\Scripts\garden", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Kivy-Garden==0.1.1', 'garden')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 483, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1335, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'garden'
```

Does this indicate a bad installation?  How might I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Kivy for windows comes in a bundle with all the prerequisites to run, since some are hard to install in windows, so it's not using you installed python.

You should go to your kivy installation folder, inside you'll find the python folder, inside is the python descriptor used for `kivy`, you can run that python exe, or use pip or easy install (i don't remember if both), like an extra advice i could saw to use PyCharm to program, it's easy to install the python modules and code, i have it myself with SqlAlchemy instaled from the PyCharm Gui (previous config here [Configure PyCharm and Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's)).

In the other hand you can configure `kivy` to run with your installed python (instructions here [Kivy with an  installed Python in Windows](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Using-Kivy-with-an-existing-Python-installation-on-Windows-%2864-or-32-bit%29)) i haven't tried myself since i use the same python included in kivy with no problems

Comment: Yes, I am using the python executable that came in the Kivy bundle for Windows.  I am attempting to get the Kivy Garden to work with this bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why pip wouldn't work, but I found a workaround.

Just download the package from pypi and run setup.py:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy-garden/0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I've found that works is to manually install flowers into the kivy garden folder. Ceremcem has a great explanation of it here: [filebrowser error in windows for kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650418/filebrowser-error-in-windows-for-kivy)

Also I found I had to explicitly use pip2 for pip to work.